# versionCode is always overwritten to -1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created a new project in android studio and one of the first things I did was to move the versionCode an versionName attributes from build.gradle to the manifest file for convenience. Then i get this weird warning saying:

> This versionCode value (1) is not used; it is always written by the
>   value specified in the Gradle build script (-1)

It started appearing in my older projects too, so it's clearly not a project specific problem. Something may happened when I updated to 0.8.14 and updated the build tools, but I have no ide what. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [official doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), gradle **overrides** some values in AndroidManifest.

The default value in DSL object for the `versionCode` is **-1**.

Then when gradle builds your apk, overrides the value in Manifest and assign the versionCode=-1

Comment: forgot to mention that the IDE didn't give me the warning before the update, but I guess i'll keep the attributes in the build script then

Answer (score 2):

You already explained the source of this problem: you can't move the versioning information to the manifest in gradle-based projects. You should use `build.grade` for the version code and name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably the Gradle build system expects you to keep the versionCode and versionName there and if it is missing, it does not know what to do. It is recommended to keep those values in the build.gradle file instead of in AndroidManifest anyway